# Java pattern for reverse iterator and iterable methods?

Tags: java

If a class implements the Iterable interface, e.g.

```
class Query implements Iterable<Query.Entry> {

    class Entry {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Entry> iterator() {
        return new EntryIterator();
    }   
}
```

then using an enhanced for is possible,

```
Query q;
// ...
for( Query.Entry e : q ) {
    // ...
}
```

but now needs to support other ways to perform iteration, e.g.

```
class Query implements Iterable<Query.Entry> {

    class Entry {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Entry> iterator() {
        return new EntryIterator();
    }   

    // new methods for reverse iteration
    public Iterator<Entry> reverseIterator() {
        return new ReverseEntryIterator();
    }

    public Iterable<Entry> reverseIterable() {
        return new Iterable<Entry>() {
            @Override
            public Iterator<Entry> iterator() {
                return new ReverseEntryIterator();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

would there be a "standard" way of doing this?  The above code adds `reverseIterable` and `reverseIterator`, but looks somewhat messy.  Maybe its better style to do without a `reverseIterable` method?

Comment: I would do it without a `reverseIterator` method. It is pretty rare for your own code to need to deal with an `Iterator` directly, and if you really want one then you can call `reverseIterable().iterator()`. Also note that you can neaten up the `reverseIterator` method by just returning `ReverseEntryIterator::new` in Java 8+.

Comment: [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) provides both iterator() and listIterator(), so this looks like a fairly reasonable approach.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to **just use  `iterator()` itself on a reverse view** of the forward order.

That would allow you to write code like this:

```
for( Query.Entry e : q.reverse() ) {
   // ...
}
```

If you already have a List representation, implementing the reverse() function can be easy, either with the O(n) `java.util.Collections.reverse(List)` or Guava's O(1) `com.google.common.collect.Lists.reverse(List)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can omit the definition of the `ReverseEntryIterator` class by using an anonymous inner class.

Since `Iterable` is a functional interface that only defines the `iterator()` method, `reverseIterable()` can be defined as a method that returns a lambda expression.

```
// new methods for reverse iteration
public Iterator<Entry> reverseIterator() {
    return new Iterator<Entry>() {

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            // ...
        }

        @Override
        public Entry next() {
            // ...
        }
    };
}

public Iterable<Entry> reverseIterable() {
    return () -> reverseIterator();
}
```